# How to create file on hyperlink click

Tags: php, fopen

I'm very new to scripting and I would like to have a script that when a user clicks on a hyperlink from my website it will run the script searching a folder and its sub-folders to make sure that there is an `index.php` file (used for photo gallery), if there isn't, create the `index.php` file and open it. I have a specific `index.php` code I want to use:

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$file = @fopen ("index.php", "w+");

if($file)
    echo fwrite($file,"MY PHP CODE HERE"); 
    fclose($file); 
}
```

This does create a file named `index.php`, however once I start putting actual code into the `MY PHP CODE HERE` section, I start getting errors like `unexpected > or (`.

Is `fopen()` not the correct thing to use?

I have not even started to look at how to add it to a hyperlink.

Comment: There is a good answer below. Before running your script, if you have CLI PHP installed/enabled, run php -l file_name.php in a command prompt of some sort to check the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your php code :

```
$file = @fopen ("index.php", "w+");

if($file)
    echo fwrite($file,"MY PHP CODE HERE"); 
    fclose($file); 
}
```

You need a { for your if like this code:

```
$file = @fopen ("index.php", "w+");

if($file) {
    echo fwrite($file,"MY PHP CODE HERE"); 
    fclose($file); 
}
```

Comment: Yup, leaving out the opening and close {} only works if you have one line of code beneath the if and else

Comment: Thanks I have tried adding the bracket as stated but still having same issue....It works with just the text but when I put in specific php coding between the quotes it barfs....see sample here...http://laurich.com/gallery/2013/gallery_check/test.php....this gives errors....but if I remove code and just have the MY PHP CODE GOES HERE text it creates the file and works....